# Pass XML node as parameter on object instantiation and then calling subnodes from it

Tags: php, xml, oop

I want to know if passing an XML node and then calling upon a method to access it is legal syntax in PHP. I tried converting to string, but that didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?
What would be the best/simplest alternative?

XML

```
<user>
    <widgets>
       <widget>Widget 1</widget>
           <stuff>
               <morestuff>Things</morestuff>
           </stuff>
           <stuff>
               <morestuff>Things</morestuff>
           </stuff>
       <widget>Widget 2</widget>
    </widgets>
</user>
```

---

PHP

```
<?php

    $xmlfile = 'widgets/widgets_files/widgets.xml';

    $widgets = array();

    $user = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfile, NULL, true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($user)->ownerDocument;


    foreach ($user->widgets->widget as $widget) {
        $new_widget = new Widget($widget);  //Where the node gets passed
        array_push($widgets, $new_widget);
    }

    //For example
    $new_widget[0]->set_subnodes();
    $new_widget[0]->get_subnodes();

    class Widget {
        private $widget;
        private $stuffArray = array();

        public function __construct($widget) {
            $this->widget = $widget;
        }

        public function set_subnodes() {
            foreach ($this->widget->stuff->morestuff as $morestuff => $value) {
                $this->stuffArray[$morestuff] = $value;
            }
        }

        public function get_subnodes() {
            foreach ($this->stuffArray as $stuff) {
                echo$stuff;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a character: `$this->widget->stuff-morestuff`

Comment: Also, references to `$stuffArray` inside the class should be `$this->stuffArray`

Comment: @SamDufel Sorry, that was typo. This code is a representation of much larger code that I'm writing, so I typed up this example to explain the idea more simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to pass XML objects as parameters to objects and to call methods on them, but there are a number of errors in your code which are stopping it from working. In particular, the XML that you are using isn't the structure that you think it is--the `stuff` and `morestuff` nodes are not children of `widget`, so none of the actions that you're trying to perform with them will work. Here's a corrected version of the XML and some PHP code that does what I think you're trying to do above:

```
$widgets = array();

# you can load your code from a file, obviously--for the purposes of the example,
# I'm loading mine using a function.
$sxe = simplexml_load_string( get_my_xml() );

foreach ($sxe->widgets->widget as $widget) {
    $new_widget = new Widget($widget);  // Where the node gets passed
    array_push($widgets, $new_widget);
}

// For example
foreach ($widgets as $w) {
    $w->set_subnodes();
    $w->get_subnodes();
}

function get_my_xml() {
    return <<<XML
<user>
    <widgets>
        <widget>Widget 1
            <stuff>
                <morestuff>Things</morestuff>
            </stuff>
            <stuff>
                <morestuff>Other Things</morestuff>
            </stuff>
        </widget>
        <widget>Widget 2
            <stuff>
               <morestuff>Widget Two's Things</morestuff>
            </stuff>
            <stuff>
               <morestuff>Widget Two's Other Things</morestuff>
            </stuff>
        </widget>
    </widgets>
</user>
XML;
}
```

The `Widget` object:

```
class Widget {

    private $widget;
    private $stuffArray = array();

    public function __construct($widget) {
        $this->widget = $widget;
    }

    public function set_subnodes() {
        # put all the "morestuff" nodes into the stuffArray
        foreach ($this->widget->xpath("stuff/morestuff") as $ms) {
            print "pushing $ms on to array" . PHP_EOL;
            array_push($this->stuffArray, $ms);
        }
    }

    public function get_subnodes() {
        foreach ($this->stuffArray as $stuff) {
            print "Running get_subnodes: got $stuff" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pushing Things on to array
pushing Other Things on to array
Running get_subnodes: got Things
Running get_subnodes: got Other Things
pushing Widget Two's Things on to array
pushing Widget Two's Other Things on to array
Running get_subnodes: got Widget Two's Things
Running get_subnodes: got Widget Two's Other Things
```